# How to know actual size of byte buffer`s content in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, buffer

I get files as byte buffers and cannot use fs.stat() method.
So I am try to use buf.length but this length refers to the amount of memory allocated for the buffer object and not actually the content size. 
For example I have file with with size 22,449 bytes. 
buf.length returns for 39804 for it.

Comment: Using node 6.10.0, buf.length gives me the exact bytes size of the file.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need [`byteLength`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding):

```js
var buff = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.txt');
console.log(Buffer.byteLength(buff));
```

For node 0.10.21 you can try this:

> **Update** `buffer.toSTring()` is unsafe, since buffers are meant to store binary data and `toString()` will attempt to do character encoding translation which will corrupt the binary data.

```js
console.log(buff.toString().length);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you know how make it works for node 0.10.21?

Comment: Thanks, buf.toString('ascii').length works perfect for me

Comment: @lor1an answer works for me too. I wasn't using `fs` but another library that returned a byte array that I needed to find out the `content-length` for.

Comment: In Node v13, Buffer.byteLength() is an instance method. Also, buf.toString().length might be skewed if you have multibyte characters, e.g. `Buffer.from("€").length // is 3`

Comment: Should know that value of `Buffer.byteLength(buff)` and `buff.toString().length` may differ and it can be problematic when uploading files using `form-data`.

Comment: divide by 1024 to get the size in kb